# Buttons in ListView not working properly - Android

Tags: android, xml, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a listView that contains buttons.Every listView Item has either Button1 or Button2. I want it so once Button1 is clicked it becomes invisible and button2 becomes visible. My current code works by making Button1 invisible but when it makes button2 visible it makes the last listView Item button2 visible. Not the button2 within its own listView.

Here is my current XML code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical">
<View android:id="@+id/topInformationBar"
            android:layout_height="6dip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/top_infomation_bar"/>
<RelativeLayout
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    android:paddingBottom="10dip"
    android:paddingTop="4dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="#454545"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        />

    <Button
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:text="button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
    <Button 
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:text="button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my ArrayAdapter that creates the ListView Items

```
class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

            public ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
                super(context, textViewResourceId);
            }

            private List<Item> items;

            public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Item> items) {
                super(context, resource, items);
                this.items = items;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = convertView;
                if (v == null) {
                    LayoutInflater vi;
                    vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

                }

                final Item p = items.get(position);
                if (p != null) {

                    Button1 = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.Button1);
                    Button2 = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.Button2);

                            Button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                    view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    Button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                }
                            });

                            Button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                    view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    Button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                }
                            });
                }
                return v;
            }
         }
```

So, if I click Button1 it makes it go Invisible, but it makes Button2 Visible on the last ListView Items. It doesn't make it Visible within its own listView.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything wrong in your code. `ListViews` 'recycle' the views it uses to render each row, so when you're scrolling up, once the top view disappears, it gets reused to render the view that appears from the bottom.

So, to solve this, you may store the state information about which button is showed/hidden in your `Item` class, and update visibility of the buttons in your `getView` method.

An example of how you could achieve this.-

**In Item.java**

```
private boolean showingButton1;

public boolean getShowingButton1() {
    return showingButton1;
}

public void setShowingButton1(boolean show) {
   showingButton1 = show;
}
```

**Update button onClickListeners**

```
Button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        p.setShowingButton1(false);
    }
});

Button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        p.setShowingButton1(true);
    }
});
```

**In your getItem method**

```
if (p != null) {
    Button1 = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.Button1);
    Button2 = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.Button2);

    if (p.getShowingButton1()) {
        Button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Button2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        Button1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying but how could I possibly do that? Any code example?

Comment: Just added a brief snippet, just in case you still didn't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I dont' understand what you are trying to do for Button2's onClick. When you click Button2, you set the visibility of the view (which is Button2) to INVISBILE and again set the visibility of Button2 to VISIBLE? Why do you toggle there?

When you click Button1, Button1 is VISIBLE and Button2 becomes INVISIBLE.

Comment: Its suppose to be button1 becomes visible once button2 is clicked. I fixed the error.

Comment: Nooo, This isn't my exact code I just narrowed down what I want to happen so it was easier to understand because I get confused trying to explain it lol.